# lxml: How to make new Element tree from given element in a tree

Tags: python, lxml

I am using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) for parsing xml data. I have to divide the xml at various nodes and write the data in each of these subtrees to separate files. lxml provides the write() method in _ElementTree class which conveniently writes the xml represented by the parse tree to a file.

So if I can make tree (_ElementTree object) by the root node of the subtree of the given node then I can easily use write() method. How to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a new ElementTree in order to write an element and its contents to a file, you can just write the result of `etree.tostring(element)`, e.g.:

```
from lxml import etree

with open("whatever.xml") as fp:
    tree = etree.parse(fp)
    i = 0
    for node in tree.xpath('//section'):
        output_filename = "output-%d.xml" % (i,)
        with open(output_filename,"w") as fp:
            fp.write(etree.tostring(node))
        i += 1
```

Comment: Your solution is elegant. Thanks :)

Comment: shouldn't it be etree.parse(fb, parser)? otherwise parser variable is obsolete

Comment: @kravietz: thanks - the `parser` isn't necessary for XML parsing, in fact, so I've removed it, and checked that the example still works

Answer (score 9):

Sorry to bother, I found the answer. Its:

```
new_tree = etree.ElementTree(node_in_tree)
```